# My program skips letting a user enter a value for one variable

Tags: java

In this program, I'm creating 2 objects from the CarOrder class with preset values. I'm then asking the user for another 2 sets of values to create 2 more objects. Unfortunately, after entering tax status for the first one, it will skip letting the user enter a value for the buyer on the second one. Why is it randomly skipping this one question?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    CarOrder speedy = new CarOrder("Speedy Rental", "Mini Cooper", 22150, 15, true);
    CarOrder zip = new CarOrder("Zip Car Co.", "Ford Fusion", 27495, 6, true);

    System.out.println("Enter Buyer: ");
    String buyer1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the type of car being purchased: ");
    String car1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the cost of this purchase: ");
    double cost1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter quantity of cars being purchased: ");
    int quantity1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter tax status: ");
    boolean tax1 = keyboard.nextBoolean();

    System.out.println("Enter Buyer: ");
    String buyer2 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the type of car being purchased: ");
    String car2 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the cost of this purchase: ");
    int cost2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter quantity of cars being purchased: ");
    int quantity2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter tax status: ");
    boolean tax2 = keyboard.nextBoolean();

    CarOrder state = new CarOrder(buyer1, car1, cost1, quantity1, tax1);
    CarOrder it = new CarOrder(buyer1, car2, cost2, quantity2, tax2);

    System.out.println("Chicago Car Wholesalers" );
    System.out.println("Oct. 30th, 2012");
    System.out.println("New Car Order Report");

}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "skipping". What are you typing, and what's the result?

Comment: Are you hitting the enter key after inputting the tax status?

Answer (score 3):

`keyboard.nextBoolean()` reads only the boolean value. Now when you continue reading with `keyboard.nextLine()` you get <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (That's the *skipping* part you're talking about).

You need to add `keyboard.nextLine();` after asking for the second buyer.

Answer (score 3):

I think `nextBoolean()` is consuming the boolean but leaving the end of line character, which your `nextLine()` then consumes as its input. So, add `keyboard.nextLine()` before asking for the second buyer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not skipping it, you're using the wrong buyer when creating "it". Look at this closely:

```
CarOrder state = new CarOrder(buyer1, car1, cost1, quantity1, tax1);
CarOrder it = new CarOrder(buyer1, car2, cost2, quantity2, tax2); // <-- This should be buyer2
```

Comment: All of this speaks to the fact that you need a subroutine. Something like "GetCarOrderFromInput()"